# A constant being assigned to another constant without errors

Tags: c, parameters, variable-assignment, pass-by-value

I'm currently learning about pointers and the concept of pass-by-value, and I have this C code block:

```
void doSomething(int b){
    b = 6;
    printf("%d", b);
}
    
int a = 5;

int main(void){
    doSomething(a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

I should get the output `65` with no errors on compilation nor on execution. By tracing the code, here is how I'm seeing it:

- Integer `a` is assigned the value `5`.
- Since C is strictly pass-by-value, `doSomething(a) == doSomething(5)`.

Now prior to running the line `b = 6;`, I'm fairly certain that `b == 5`. So by running the line, the program is effectively reading:

```
5 = 6;
```

A constant (for a lack of a better term on my part) is being assigned to another constant. In Python this would have failed with a syntax error, and it makes sense to have an error. Why doesn't it raise a syntax error?

Comment: It's great that you're learning, but here's one thing to internalize very early: **Stay away from global variables**. Declare things in the scope they're used.

Comment: `b` is not a constant. It is a variable. `b = 6;` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Since `doSomething()` returns `void`, the all calls to it are "equivalent" as in "not that it matters because it's not anything".

Comment: Yeah, function parameters are variables with automatic storage duration - they can be used as such, eg. assigned to, as you demonstrate.  They are certainly not constants.

Comment: @tadman If it's about `int a = 5;` being declared prior to `main()`, I feel that it's irrelevant to the problem at hand. I'm aware of how passing global variables into a function is dangerous, and this is merely a learning example. What I do not understand is how `5 = 6;` can run without problems.

Comment: It's just worth moving it into `main` to make it clear where it's used.

Comment: First things first.  Do you understand why `int c = 5; c = 6;` is legal, what it does, and why it is not assigning a constant to another constant?  That's effectively all that's going on here.

Comment: corvelk Before "So by running the line, the program is effectively reading: 5 = 6;", your thoughts were fairly good.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I understand that. I answered my own question below to show my erroneous thought. `b` being declared in the parameter threw me off. Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the C 2018 standard says function calls are executed, in 6.5.2.2 4:

> In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument…

What this means is that, in the function definition with `void doSomething(int b)`, `b` is defined to be a variable (technically an object) on its own, and, when the function is called with `doSomething(a)` or `doSomething(5)`, the value of `a` or `5` is assigned to `b`, as if you did `b = a` or `b = 5`. It is just an assignment; it does not create any enduring connection between `b` and `a` or `5`.

Inside the function, `b` is a variable, so of course you can execute the assignment `b = 6`. This simply assigns `6` to the variable `b`.

Here is more about how parameters are their own variables. 3.16 defines *parameter* as:

> … object declared as part of a function declaration or definition that acquires a value on entry to the function,…

6.9.1 9 says:

> Each parameter has automatic storage duration; its identifier is an lvalue…

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your debugger you're going to see that there's two variables in play here, the `a` which is, in your code, global in scope, and `b`, which is local to the `doSomething()` function.

These are *two completely independent variables*. When you call the `doSomething()` function, imagine the following happens:

```c
stack_push(a);
call(doSomething);
```

Where inside of `doSomething()` the compiler does something like:

```c
int b = stack_pop();
...
```

That's how a "copy" is made.

> Note that this model for thinking about variables is an approximation and an optimizing compiler may do something *completely* different so long as the same result is achieved, as per the C spec.

Answer (score 1):

`5 = 6;` is not same as `b = 6;`

`b = 6;` assigns value 6 to variable `b` , `b` has automatic storage that's a different story

`5 = 6;` is not a valid expression in `C`, you have misunderstood the concept thinking both are same.
Run the below program to see an error:

```
void doSomething(int b){
    b = 6;
    5 = 6;
    printf("%d", b);
}
    
int a = 5;

int main(void){
    doSomething(a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Now you will get error for the 3rd line:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
> 5 = 6;

refer [lvalues and rvalues](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lvalue-and-rvalue-in-c-language/)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to just put `5 = 6;` in `main()`. It yielded a compilation error similar to the one in Python and Johnny Mopp's and Martin James's comments now make sense.

`b` is indeed a variable and not an actual constant. I was under the impression that pass-by-value was to only pass what the variable contained and exactly that, and disregarded the idea that `b` was a variable, thinking that the function only allowed integers and that `b` was not anything but a placeholder, different from a variable.

I was under the impression that `b` was **exactly** `5`, and not a variable **assigned** the value `5`.

What I am currently seeing in my head is this:

- Integer `a` is assigned the value `5`.
- Since C is strictly pass-by-value, `doSomething(a) == doSomething(5)`.
- `b` is assigned the value `5` on invocation of `doSomething(5)`.
- `b` is assigned the value `6` as per the line `b = 6;`.
- ...so on and so forth.

Thank you everyone for the comments and answers!